# King Robota: Does he speak for himself?

Tags: control, software

I want to know if its currently possible for a robot to speak by it self as `King Robota` does, or is just someone speaking on his behalf?

[Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UYI2UDpQtv4)

Comment: Sorry, but this post was presented for review to me, so I have to be honest; It does nothing to further robotic knowledge at this site, in any form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not only is a human voice behind this (likely through a vocoder), I believe you are looking at a mechanized costume and not an actual robot -- [someone is inside](http://kingrobota.com/faq.html).

Using fake robots to attract crowds has worked since ["Elektro" at the 1939 World's Fair (video)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T35A3g_GvSg).  You can also [buy your own King Robota suit](http://digitaldiscountproducts.com/WP/2012/04/18/start-your-own-robot-business-2012/) if you want to take up this form of entertainment yourself.

A more interesting question is how the costume's mouth reacts to the incoming speech, to emulate actual speaking.

Comment: Fake automata go back a lot further than [Elektro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elektro), with [The Turk (1770)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Turk) being the most famous example.